# Selenium standalone starts Firefox, which stays blank

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I'm using Firefox 23.0 and Selenium standalone server 2.35.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.  I have a simple test case file: open Google, enter "ohai", and search for it.

I'm trying to run it using the .jar file:

`java -jar "C:\Selenium Scripts\selenium.jar" -htmlSuite *firefox "http://www.google.com" "C:\Selenium Scripts\Automated Tests\testing.htm" "C:\Selenium Scripts\Automated Tests\results\Testing.Results.htm"`

It does start the Firefox browser.  However, nothing happens.  Firefox remains blank, and no errors display in the Selenium output.

```
Aug 15, 2013 6:20:13 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
18:20:14.008 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.25-b01
18:20:14.009 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
18:20:14.018 INFO - v2.35.0, with Core v2.35.0. Built from revision c916b9d
18:20:14.126 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.
1:4444/wd/hub
18:20:14.128 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
18:20:14.128 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server
/driver]
18:20:14.129 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
18:20:14.130 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
18:20:14.176 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@c07014
a
18:20:14.177 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
18:20:14.194 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
18:20:14.194 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@16db3bc
jar:file:/C:/Kiln/QAScripts/Selenium%20Scripts/selenium.jar!/customProfileDirCUS
TFFCHROME
18:20:14.352 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
18:20:15.554 INFO - Launching Firefox...
```

But nothing happens!  No unusual errors in the error console (only the known ones, aUrl issues and chrome.manifest and the like), no errors in the logging, nothing unusual when I run with `-debug`... it just sits here.

And it worked for me last week...

What should I do?

Comment: What did you upgrade in the last week? FF or selenium? Try downgrading one of them

Comment: Yep, tried it with FF18 and Selenium standalone v2.29.0; no dice.

Comment: Just now tried it: still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: my test opened Firefox window, but nothing actually happened (it stayed blank for some time).

I had this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
```

**Solution**:
Try to download and include in your project the latest version of Selenium driver. It helped me and now I can execute all my tests - works fine with the latest firefox (**33.0**) and Selenium driver for java in version **2.43.1** (I had problems with version **2.42.x**).